# Use Ignore attribute with Symfony Serializer

Tags: symfony

In my Symfony 6 project I use the symfony Serializer with this configuration.

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml

framework:

    serializer:
        name_converter: 'serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
        enable_annotations: true
        default_context:
            datetime_format: Y-m-d

    annotations:
        enabled: true
```

I was expecting that #[Ignore] attribute excludes the fields from json. But it has no effect.

```
class Event {

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    #[Ignore]
    private $id;

    ...
}
```

I have also tried to define the serializer in the controller based on [attributes-groups](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups) and [ignoring-attributes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes) but still the result is the same.

```
    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
    $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory)],[new JsonEncoder()]);
    return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($events,'json'));
```

What did i miss, or why it does not exlude the fields based on Ignore attribute?
Is it possible to only use the yml configuration to activate the Ignore attribute?

The "datetime_format" changes the output datetime format, but "name_converter" also does not change the field names from camelCase to sanke_case.

I guess the reason could be that `GetSetMethodNormalizer` has higher priority compare to `ObjectNormalizer` and it does not use the serilizer configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using controller-based as in the documentation, you can set the Ignore annotation/attribute on getId() for extra handling, like:

```
#[Ignore]
public function getId(): ?string
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your configuration is correct, you can use this command to verify your configuration:
`php bin/console debug:config framework serializer`

if use serializer by youself please set `nameConverter` in second argumant of `ObjectNormalizer`. see code `withoutContainer` function`

but if you want use symfony configuration you should use service in container so use this style see code `withContainer` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Event;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/without-container')]
    public function withoutContainer(): Response
    {

        $event = new Event();
        $event->setName('Published Email');
        $event->setIsPublished(true);
        
        $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter());
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer],[new JsonEncoder()]);

        return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($event,'json'));
        //"{\"name\":\"Published Email\",\"is_published\":true}"
    }

    #[Route('/with-container', name: 'app_home')]
    public function withContainer(SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
    {
        $event = new Event();
        $event->setName('Published Email');
        $event->setIsPublished(true);

        return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($event,'json'));
        // "{\"name\":\"Published Email\",\"is_published\":true}"
    }
}
```